# The selected boot device failed.....Ubuntu 15.10 OS will not load

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

So i am trying to install ubuntu and get it to work on my laptop dual boot with Win 10

I have two separate drives: one the ssd which i have the windows os which i dont want to touch

On the other drive i am trying to install and load ubuntu 15.10

I used to have linux mint and it worked fine but due to some hardware problems with its kernel and too much tampering in order to get things to work i have decided to move over to ubuntu

But unfortunately i cannot get Ubuntu to install and work correctly

I have an Alienware 15 r2 laptop and have tired over and over again to install Ubuntu

I have tried to find the answer to this problem but i have not found anything direct and straightforward, i dont know how to tamper with EFI as some of the solutions suggest

Isnt there a simple straightforward solution to this?

Comment: Be aware that Mint uses unmodified Ubuntu kernels. Thus, if Mint's kernel didn't work for you, Ubuntu's won't, either, unless the problem has been fixed with a kernel update (which may well have happened). Your question is very vague, so it's unclear precisely what's not working or how you've tried to install the system. Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post the `RESULTS.txt` file it generates to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) for us to see. Also please describe the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: it wont even boot into Ubuntu it just gives the error "The selected boot device failed. Press any key to restart" 

and then i am back into windows(unless i choose again in boot options to go into ubuntu which gives that error again)

Comment: The only way i can get into Ubuntu is if i go through the live USB and that is the "Try Ubuntu" version

Comment: You can run Boot Info Script from the live Ubuntu disk.

Comment: now i cant even install linux mint any more, it wont boot into linux mint either , just gives me the minimal grub screen and doesnt let me go any further

Comment: okay here is the pastebin from boot-info paste.ubuntu.com/14675452/

Comment: Try booting the live disk and typing `sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -B`.  This should remove a suspicious-looking EFI boot entry that may be causing problems. Then run the Ubuntu installer from the live disk. If that doesn't work, try using my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive to boot to Ubuntu. If that works, install rEFInd by using the PPA or Debian package.

Comment: hi @RodSmith

okay i have narrowed down the problem , basically i can boot into ubuntu live usb and install ubuntu however there seems to be a problem with the installer

it doesnt seem to install the grub bootloader correctly , i did the very same thing with Linux Mint and it installed fine but with the 15.10 live ubuntu usb it seems to not work very well

Comment: @RodSmith when i go back into the usb live disc after installing and the boot loader failing to start with the same error given as the one mentioned in my OP, i tried to do boot repair according to the instructions on the ubuntu community wiki and i find that there is two options in advanced options grub location , one is as it shows in the website https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI, and another is simply the windows drive/boot 

ive already tried to fix and unlink the /boot/efi and it did nothing but when i try to unlink the one with just /win drive/boot it goes through a purge reinstall

Comment: @RodSmith and it takes a long time to do and i am not sure how it will end , its still doing it for about 10 minutes now and continuing

Comment: I suspect you may be booting your installer in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode some of the time. This would explain your sporadic failures to install GRUB, since your disk is set up for EFI-mode booting. Try disabling the CSM (aka "legacy boot support") in your firmware. You could also try booting with a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) If that works, install rEFInd by using the PPA or Debian package. (I gave you that advice earlier, but you seem to have ignored it.)

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Ubuntu CD,  choose "Try Ubuntu"  and install from the desktop,  with the option of installing proprietary software  (I think,  but it says proprietary something or other),   there will be an icon on the desktop allowing you to install from there.  This method has always worked for me.

You are probably going to have a  few driver issues,  but upon installation and restart go to, System Settings/Software & Updates and click on the 'Additional Drivers' tab and pick the alternative device option.

BTW,  this works in Mint also.

You then may want to go to the driver website and install any available updates as Ubuntu may not have the latest version for the specific hardware.

Comment: okay i will try this

Comment: did not work unfortunately